# Penne Pasta in bulk

Tags: pasta

Can you give portion advice for cooking the dry penne pasta for 200?  We want to mix the pasta with a meat spaghetti sauce.   Is there a general rule for pounds of pasta per 100 servings?

Comment: I thought this must be a duplicate, but can't find an older question. Anybody seen one?

Comment: @rumtscho Portion sizes were discussed in answers to this question, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43353/how-do-i-cook-and-hold-pasta-for-200-people but I can't find an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as a standard serving of anything really

It's always just serving size * number of people + some for wastage

Cook 100 g of your pasta, and work out what percent makes a serving; use an accurate set of scales you can divide the cooked serving weight by total cooked weight. This ratio can then be applied to 100 g dry, to work out the dry per person

Then multiply that by number of people, and add few percent for cooking and serving wastage

Comment: Also don't forget to consider the occasion. Is the food meant to be an entire meal for hungry people or are they having a light snack at a working banquet where they may expect to eat additional food or something? +1 for "cook some, figure out how much a serving should be, and weigh it."