# How much penne pasta for 10 trays (20x12)

Tags: storage-method, cheese, pasta

I need to make 10 large party trays (20x12) of baked pasta with three kinds of cheese for 200 people. Please suggest the following:

1. How many lbs of pasta I will need per tray?
2. tips to make/boil such large quantities at home in batches. (I have 4-5 stock pots and two refrigerator) .Should I boil all the pasta and refrigerated and then add sauce and layer with cheese next day or should do mixing and layering before refrigeration? Also how much in advance can I refreigrate?
3. I am thinking of keeping the boiled pasta in trays to avoide multiple transfer/pots and adding sauce and cheese into the tray of boiled pasta and mixing it and adding a top layer of sauce and mozzarella cheese on the top. Any tips or cons?
4. I m thinking mozzarella, ricotta, and Parmesan cheese. Could you please tell me how much each cheese is good to put per tray? What kind of parmesan cheese is budget friendly?
5. I'm using store-bought Ragu marinara sauce ( original). How much sauce I may need per tray?
6. how long should I bake the refrigerated pasta/pre-assembled?

Any tips or suggestions are welcome and I am a novice. Doing it for a cause. Thanks so much.

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43353/how-do-i-cook-and-hold-pasta-for-200-people for some hints.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Here's hoping that one of our members who currently works in catering will have answers for you.